# Downloading QT?

Tags: qt

I've been trying to get QT, it's not as easy as it used to be.
I downloaded the source code and it didn't come with the main program.
And when I click 'try now' on their website, it asks me for a company name, which I'm only downloading QT to learn more.

What do I do? or how can I get QT properly?

Comment: did you try pirating it?  aaargg matey

Comment: I can't seem to find any torrents.
Also, is it allowed to talk about pirating in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 5):

1, go here http://qt-project.org/downloads

2, click on: Linux, windows, mac or source code downloads

3, if you aren't sure which OS you need just look around you:

- if you are in a Starbucks and/or wearing jeans that cost more than a laptop - you need Mac
- if you are in front of a beige computer or in a beuge cubicle - you need windows
- if you naturally tall, dark and handsome and the life and soul of the party - you need linux
- if you look down and can't see your sandals because of your beard - other Unix builds are available.

Comment: On that page: `Qt Creator 2.6.1 is included in the Qt 5.0 binary releases. If you need a standalone installer, please select the file according to your operating system from the list below to get the latest Qt Creator for your computer`

Comment: There are links to download the source as a zip/tar.gz or from git. Just download the zip and use 'configure' to build natively on any OS

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you wandered into the section for commercial developers. You probably want the free version.

The free (LGPL) version of Qt can be downloaded from the Qt Project's website:
http://qt-project.org/downloads

If you've purchased a commercial licence, you can log in and download from Digia's website:
http://qt.digia.com/Product/

Comment: The source code doesn't seem to come with 'QT Creator' or do i not need this part of the program?

Comment: Depends what you want. You don't need Qt Creator to develop Qt applications, but is is a very nice tool.

Comment: Thanks, well 5.0 apparently has it.